# How to structure standard Python project (modules, libraries) for future use in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I'm currently developing a Python project which is growing and I may implement it as a webapp in GAE in the future.

As the project is growing I'm pruning potentially reusable code into separate packages & modules, which at present are on my PYTHONPATH.

Do you have any advice on how to structure my project, and reusable packages so that it will fit nicely into a GAE project in the future?

Looking at recommendations on GAE project structure in other posts (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458/project-structure-for-google-app-engine) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546199/python-and-app-engine-project-structure) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710861/how-to-import-modules-in-google-app-engine)) seem fairly flat - is that the best way to go?

What about 3rd party packages/modules?  Is it best to bite the bullet and use [VirtualEnv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) from the beginning?

Thanks very much.
Prembo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put your various libraries in packages off the root directory of your app. The root directory is automatically added to your app's `sys.path`.

If you wish you can put them in a `lib` directory off the root, you can do so, but you'll have to write a module that adds that directory to the end of `sys.path`, and import it before you import anything from `lib`.

Using virtualenv is an option, but I personally don't think it gains you much, since you can't run a virtualenv in production, and the `dev_appserver` emulates the production environment.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you about GAE in particular, but I can tell you that biting the bullet has nothing to do with it - using VirtualEnv (and virtualenvwrapper) will make your Python development smoother, simpler, and easier all around.

The over head is low, the benefits are many.

Switch. Now.

Answer (score 2):

My master [thesis](https://bitbucket.org/kristop/easy-tube) as a student was implemented in App Engine. The project is open source and you can use it however you like, I hope you will get the idea and you might adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Hey -- I tried to check out your project but got "Error: You do not have access to this repository." at BitBucket. Is it still available?

Comment: I removed the previous version and I am close to finish the second one, misconfiguration. You can try again now. CoffeeScript is also included in the structure ;)

Comment: For large scale projects I would strongly suggest having a look at this architecture http://gae-init.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

The GAE Python SDK creates its own Virtual Environment when running on your local environment, so virtualenv won't help you much. There are frameworks like web2py and django-nonrel that works well with GAE, if you're up to porting your code, or at least take inspiration on their folder structure.